# C# - Access array without null exception

Tags: c#, try-catch

I have to set these variables through with the QueryString array:

```
UtmSource = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["utm_source"];
UtmMedium = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["utm_medium"];
UtmCreative = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["utm_creative"];
UtmCampaign = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["utm_campaign"];
UtmTerm = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["utm_term"];
UtmContent = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["utm_content"];
Tag1 = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["utm_source"];
Tag2 = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["m"];
```

Some keys in the query string might throw null exception.

I don't want to wrap each var in try catch and I don't want to wrap all with try catch because if the first one fails, the entire will be null/avoided.

How can I safely access these variables?

Comment: You might try adding a function that gets called with  the QueryString name and handle the try-catch inside the function (set the return value to default if it fails).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about using a method like this when you want to safely get a query string parameter's value?

```
public string getQueryStringValueOrEmpty(string key)
{
  string result = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[key];

  if(result == null)
  {
    result = string.Empty;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would use the **null-coalescing** operator to make it nice and simple

```
UtmSource = Request.QueryString["utm_source"] ?? "DefaultValue"
```

You can read more about the operator at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

```
UtmSource = (Request.QueryString.ContainsKey("utm_source")) ? Request.QueryString["utm_source"] : null;
```

Only those that are valid will be set to something, the others will be set to `null` (if they are nullable)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative that uses the built in ParseQueryString and a NameValueCollection to skip some busy work.  I tried to use the .IsNullOrEmpty as well, but my console app was balking at it.

```
Uri tempUri = new Uri("http://microsoft.com/Default.aspx?IsMonkeyBusiness=true&Name=Daniel&Test=");
string sQuery = tempUri.Query;
NameValueCollection qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(sQuery);
foreach (string s in qscoll)
    foreach (string v in qscoll.GetValues(s))
        if (!(v=="")) Console.WriteLine("{0}",v);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["utm_term"]))
            {
            }
```

can solve this..
 or;

write a extended function to check the object is null or not and use it like

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["utm_term"].checkNull("");
```

and give that function a return value, in this example its "" and empty string..